# How to use log4j 1.2.x multiple loggers in a single class for different appenders?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a requirement to log all security events to a separate appender.  However, these security events can happen in multiple different classes.  I am using Log4j 1.2.6.  Upgrading my logger package to something newer is not an option.

Ideally, I would like to be able to continue using the same naming conventions of my current loggers (classname), but then I would have no way to configure the appenders differently.

Is there an easy way I can make all my security loggers extend a custom logger class and then configure log4j to log all output from any child of this custom logger/class to a separate appender?  Ideally, I would like to say any child of SecurityLogger.class should be logged via a specific appender.

The problem, as far as I know it, is that all configuration is based on logger name, not logger class.  Consequently, I would need to modify the logger names.

Is there another option?